# Dropdown hace saltar overflow-y

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un scroll horizontal para ver todas las opciones y en este scroll horizontal tengo un select que al desplegarse me crea otro scroll vertical, me gustaría que la ventana del select se superpusiese al scroll horizontal y me la mostrase fuera del scroll

El código básicamente es un **overflow-x: auto**, también he probado con **overflow-x: scroll...** La lista de items horizontales está dentro de un **display flex** y los select son de Bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.detail {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="detail">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en tu archivo de css, en esta línea.

```
.dropdown, .dropleft, .dropright, .dropup {
    position: relative;
}
```

Tu objeto esta en posición absoluta pero al usar relative en el div padre lo estas condicionando al tamaño del div padre, elimina el `position: relative;` o cámbialo a position: inherit; por ejemplo, para que los elementos absolutos no se vean condicionados por el tamaño del div padre.

Ejemplo:

```css
.detail {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.dropdown, .dropleft, .dropright, .dropup {
    position: inherit!important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="detail">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```